# PL/SQL error : identifier 'NAME' must be declared

Tags: sql, plsql

I have to call a procedure from a package p_name but it gives error as identifier 'NAME' must be declared

```
DECLARE  
    V V_NAME;  
    V1 VARCHAR2(30);  
    v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);  
BEGIN  
    SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME BULK COLLECT INTO V from ALL_PROCEDURES
    where  OBJECT_NAME='p_name';

    FOR I IN 1..V.COUNT LOOP  
        name:='p_name';  
        v_sql:='begin'||name||'.'||V(I)||';'||'END;';  
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;  
    END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: The variable `name` that you use here `    name:='p_name';  
    v_sql:='begin'||name||'.'||V(I)||';'||'END;';` is not declared.

Comment: Also `'begin'||name` should be `'begin '||name`, and you need to specify the package owner, and maybe some other filters to ensure that `owner.object_name.procedure_name` is a procedure and doesn't require parameters etc. I'd post a fixed version but there are too many issues with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only problem, it should be ok like so:

```
DECLARE  
V V_NAME;  
V1 VARCHAR2(30);
NAME VARCHAR2(7);
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);  
BEGIN  
SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME BULK COLLECT INTO V from ALL_PROCEDURES where   
lower(OBJECT_NAME)='p_name';  
FOR I IN 1..V.COUNT LOOP  
    name:=' p_name';  
    v_sql:='begin'||name||'.'||V(I)||';'||'END;';  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;  
END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: i did the changes, now it says invalid sql statement.

Comment: @varad - now this is a subject of a new thread, as it doesn't concern this one here. What I can say here is the following - this is what gets into v_sql and is trying to get processed: `begin p_name.procedure_name ; end;` - this is not a correct syntax, as your procedures probably have parameters.

Comment: Also, have in mind that `all_procedures` lists not only procedures, but functions - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm#i1585339. In case of a function the syntax is not correct. You're assuming that the package p_name has all the procedures and functions, but if its not, then it's a wrong syntax also.

Comment: i'm definate that it is a procedure. can you tell me a proper way to call that procedure?

Comment: But this is dynamic code. You can't know that there will never be a function in the specified package, or a procedure that requires parameters etc.

Comment: @varad - If you're positive that the package P_NAME has onlt procedures with no parameters, you can use the same code, but change the statement to `SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME BULK COLLECT INTO V from ALL_PROCEDURES where   
lower(OBJECT_NAME)='p_name';` - by default they are uppercased there.